# How to make a php dynamic table showing only the last 20 values from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a php table that displays data from MySQL table. This is working perfectly. However, the MySQL table keeps getting updated and so my php table gets really long and big. I just want to keep it short, so I just want it to display the last 20 items on the table if possible.

Also the table doesn't update dynamically, to see the new updates you have to keep refreshing the page and *I would like it if it could keep updating on its own*. 
[Here](http://gtap.strangled.net/test_chart/table3.php) is the page of how the (long) table looks.

Here is my php code as of now:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$pass"); 
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con); //database name
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table"); //table

    echo "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='ver-minimalist'>
    <tr>
    <th>Photoresistor</th>
    <th>Accelerometer</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Photoresistor'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Accelerometer'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

I know I'm going to have to make a loop but I'm not sure which one would be the best option. Please, I would really appreciate the help.

The MySQL table does have an ID -primary key if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Make your query this:

```
SELECT * FROM $db_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Limit allows you to limit the amount of results you get from a query. By sorting by ID you can get the last 20 results in your table.

Comment: it displays 20 items however it displays them in an upside down order? [link] (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/capture123a.jpg/)

Comment: @Erin i did and it shows the first 20 items instead of last 20